# Azure App Service API gets FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyApi.xml when trying to start swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, swagger-ui, azure-api-apps

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 API deployed to Azure App Services. I am deploying to a DEV slot.

I am using Swagger, which works fine on my localhost, but when I go to the URL of by DEV slot and use /swagger, I get the error;

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyApi.xml
```

I have the following in my *.csproj file;

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And when I go to Kudu for the DEV slot, I can see the MyApi.xml file in the /site/wwwroot folder. If I edit it in Kudu, I can see that the content is as expected.

In my project's Startup.cs class --> Configure method, I have;

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

This is similar to the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919553/azure-app-service-cant-start-because-it-cant-find-swagger-documentation-xml-us) but in that post, the file was not actually showing up in wwwroot, whereas in my case, it does.

The API otherwise works correctly in that I can use Postman to test all of the APIs endpoints in the DEV slot. It is just that when I try to access DEV slot URL + /swagger from Chrome, I get the FileNotFound exception.

My Startup.cs --> ConfigureServices method has the following;

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    options =>
    {
        // integrate xml comments
        options.IncludeXmlComments(XmlCommentsFilePath);
    });
```

and the XmlCommentsFilePath method is below;

```
private static string XmlCommentsFilePath
{
    get
    {
        var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        var fileName = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
        return Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
    }
}
```

I assume that the Swagger setup is correct since it works locally and the error I get when deployed to the DEV slot is the FileNotFound pointing to D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyApi.xml where that file **actually does exist** according to Kudu for that slot.

**UPDATE 1**

I also tried the recommendation for ASP.NET 2.2 in [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968322/xml-comments-file-could-not-be-found-swagger) with no luck.

What am I missing here?